# what does `... || exit;` mean in php

Tags: php

I read find some use `|| exit;` what does this mean?

```
$this->auth($token) || exit;
$if(IS_GET){
    echo($_GET['echostr']);exit;
} else {
    $xml = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $xml || exit;
}
```

Comment: It means OR exit. So if $this->auth($token) returns false, the program will exit

Comment: It's the same as the horrible `.. OR die()`.

Comment: @iswinky In what world do programmers know OR before ||? It's a sad place we live in.

Comment: well @Arlaud Pierre, looking at Damonflu profile, I would guess he is not primarily a programmer as it says "Ec-Commerce" on his profile, don't jump to conclusions and make people feel bad.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms Not trying to make people feel bad, but it shows the problem with having many aliases for the same thing in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->auth($token) || exit;` means:

If `$this->auth($token)` returns false, perform `exit()`

Comment: This is caused by the way `or` statements are read. It evaluates the first condition, and if it is true then it does not need to read the second statement. However, if it returns false, it tries to evaluate the second expression to see if it is true; however, when evaluating the second expression it simply exits.